# Jenkins - having several "flavors" of one build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a whole bunch of products to build (20+), each product builds on 3 platforms, and now I've had the request that each product have 3 different types of build -
1) Whenever the SCM changes.  Don't clear the workspace, do a subset of unit tests.
2) Every night at midnight.  Clear the workspace first, do all unit tests.
3) Release candidate, triggered manually.  Tag the files in the SCM with the release number, clear the workspace, do all unit tests, collect the output from all 3 platforms in a single archive.

I've created a multi-configuration "matrix" job for each product that builds the product on each of the 3 platforms, but now I'm not sure the best way to include the 3 types of build - I'd rather not create 3 copies of each job, that sounds like a maintenance nightmare to me.

Suggestions on the least-unpleasant way to do this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complicated the actual build part in these jobs is for you. However, I would create 3 jobs since they are significantly different.

However, job2 seems like it is a subset of job3. So you might be able to work something out that job3 triggers job2 and does only the prebuild and postbuild work. I have no good idea for combining job1 and 2 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 can be accomplished either as a seperate job or batch task. In the advanced features of the job, You can have job 2 use the workspace of job one. For Maven Jobs it's configurable in Build -> Checkbox for Use Custom Workspace. For free for jobs it's under "Advanced Project Options"

Number 3 can be done with 3 or 4 different plugins (Subversion Tagging plugin, Artifactory  Plugin with Artifactory Pro, Promoted Builds, Release plugin)

Answer (score 0):

well separate the requirements...

you have **different builds**... in that they will be totally different, different code, or platform or something big.

you have **parameterized builds**... these will be built on the same code base with with different parameters

you have **different triggers**... ie. a timer, or a check-in.

You must make a separate job for different builds,
 you can make a different job for parameterized builds...
for triggers, each job can have multiple triggers...
 so the reason you would make a separate build for a different trigger would be something like if you had a long running set of tests that you just wanted to test nightly rather than at every check-in

and for parameters they can be filled in for each manual job start, or perhaps batched into a file that is imported... you can build as much configuration management as you want really, it is a very flexible tool.